# filter out unneeded object properties for interface in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, prisma

As background, I'm using Prisma (graphql), mysql2 (nodejs) and typescript.

I'm using an interactive command line script to connect to mysql2.

This is the warning I am seeing:

> Ignoring invalid configuration option passed to Connection: type. This
>   is currently a warning, but in future versions of MySQL2, an error
>   will be thrown if you pass an invalid configuration options to a
>   Connection

This is how I instantiate mysql2, in my MysqlConnector class:

```
this.connectionPromise = await this.mysql.createConnection(this.connectionOptions)
```

"connectionOptions" is set in the class constructor:

```
constructor(connectionDetails: MysqlConnectionDetails) {
```

This is my type definition:

```
export interface MysqlConnectionDetails {
  host: string
  port: number
  user: string
  password: string
  database?: string
}
```

This is the type definition of the object that I pass into my MysqlConnector class:

```
export interface DatabaseCredentials {
  type: DatabaseType
  host: string
  port: number
  user: string
  password: string
  database?: string
  alreadyData?: boolean
  schema?: string
  ssl?: boolean
  filter?: any
}
```

So, I am passing in an object that has additional parameters that mysql2 does not want/need. I am new to Typescript. I tried this, before passing the object in to the MysqlConnector class:

```
let forDeletion = ['type', 'alreadyData']
connector = new MysqlConnector(credentials.filter(item => !forDeletion.includes(item)))
```

But I get an error, saying "filter" is not a property on the type "DatabaseCredentials", and I concluded this is probably not the right way to do this.

I assumed there is a way in Typescript (through tsconfig) automatically to filter out properties that are not in the receiving type. "MysqlConnectionDetails" doesn't have a property "type", in its definition, so it gets it dynamically, when I pass in another type.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there's a specific TypeScript way to deal with this, but you can use destructuring/spread for this:

```
const { type, ...validCredentials } = credentials;
```

This essentially picks `type` out of credentials, and `validCredentials` will contain the rest of the properties.

The reason `.filter` didn't work is because filter is a prototype method on arrays, not objects.

Comment: I get this error: Type 'MysqlConnectionDetails' has no property 'type' and no string index signature. I created a generic gist that illustrates what I'm trying to do: https://gist.github.com/jamesmbowler/7d014f9000fb7376174415ce6ba8c12a

Comment: In your gist, I think your test function needs to accept an argument of type `DatabaseCredentials`, not `MysqlConnectionDetails`. You should also `console.log(validCredentials)` instead of `connectionDetails`.

Comment: If I uncomment this line, const { type, ...validCredentials } = connectionDetails;, I get an error: Type 'MysqlConnectionDetails' has no property 'type' and no string index signature. Which is why I am not logging validCredentials. The whole point is that I want to convert from the "parent" (quotes, because it's not a real parent) to MysqlConnectionDetails, which has the right params for mysql2.

Comment: `getDbCredentials()` returns an object of type `DatabaseCredentials`. You are passing that object to the `test` function. The `test` function is expecting to receive an object of type `MysqlConnectionDetails`. You need to change the `test` function to be: `function test(connectionDetails:DatabaseCredentials)`

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using Array methods, `.map()` is probably most helpful:

```js
let obj2big = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }

// let's assume what you want from this is { a: 1, c: 3 }

let arr = [obj2big]

let result = arr.map(i=>({a:i.a, c: i.c}))

console.log(result[0])
```