# Filter existing object properties in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, graphql

I have an `any` object in typescript which I need to shape so it is valid for a given interface.

I need a way to create the new object in a way that cleans out the properties which don't belong to the class definition, and adds the missing properties.

A code sample could be:

```
interface ImyInterface {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c?:string;
};

let myObject = {
  a: "myString",
  d: "other value"
};
```

My question is: is there a way to convert/filter `myObject` so it fits the interface `ImyInterface` definition, and gets transformed to this

```
console.log (JSON.stringify(objectA));
> {a: 'myString', b: null}
```

Comment: Please, show the code you already have and comment the parts you're struggling with.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a *better* way, but off the top of my head this works:

```
    let otherObject: ImyInterface = { a: null, b: null };
    let x: ImyInterface = { ...otherObject, ...myObject };
```

The first line defines an object of the desired interface.

The second line defines a new object of the desired interface and copies into that object all of the properties from `otherObject` and then any properties from `myObject` that conform to the interface.

NOTE: If you try it just with this:

```
let x: ImyInterface = { ...myObject };
```

You will see an error that some of the properties for the interface are missing. Hence the reason to create a "complete" object first (`otherObject` in my example).

Comment: Thanks @DeborahK, looks like a good approach. In my application I have many interfaces (generated from a GraphQL definition file), and I have to ensure that the objects being sent conforms to those defined in the interface. So, although I like your  solution, it is not scalable to many interface definitions, as I'd have to create one empty object per interface definition and the code would get very messy.

Comment: Someone asked a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52190091/filter-out-unneeded-object-properties-for-interface-in-typescript Their first solution was similar to mine. The second one doesn't seem like it would "scale" either.

Comment: You could maybe take advantage of this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-transformer-keys ... but that isn't built in so could be a pain ... and still may not scale.

Comment: The information here looks interesting as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425568/interface-type-check-with-typescript